# Grouping rows of large dataset in R

Tags: r, loops, data-analysis

I am trying to calculate driver activity using GPS data. I've written a loop that calculates the difference in time between two consecutive points in a dataframe over the range of values, summing it as it goes.

Here is an example of my data:

```
  DriveNo       Date.and.Time Latitude Longitude
1     156 2014-01-31 23:00:00 41.88367  12.48778
2     187 2014-01-31 23:00:01 41.92854  12.46904
3     297 2014-01-31 23:00:01 41.89107  12.49270
4      89 2014-01-31 23:00:01 41.79318  12.43212
5      79 2014-01-31 23:00:01 41.90028  12.46275
6     191 2014-01-31 23:00:02 41.85231  12.57741
```

Reprex:

```r
taxi_noOutlier <- structure(list(DriveNo = c(156, 187, 297, 89, 79, 191),
  Date.and.Time = structure(c(1391209200.73917, 1391209201.14846,
    1391209201.22007, 1391209201.47085, 1391209201.63114, 1391209202.04855),
    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),
  Latitude = c(41.883670807, 41.928543091, 41.891067505, 41.793178558,
    41.900276184, 41.852306366),
  Longitude = c(12.48777771, 12.469037056, 12.492704391, 12.432122231,
    12.46274662, 12.577406883)),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the loop:

```
taxi_156 <- filter(taxi_noOutlier, DriveNo == 156)
datelist = taxi_156$Date.and.Time
dlstandard = as.POSIXlt(datelist)
diffsum <- as.numeric(sum(Filter(function(x) x <= 60, difftime(tail(dlstandard, -1), head(dlstandard, -1), units = 'secs'))))
print(paste("The total activity time for driver #156 is ", diffsum))
```

Which gives an output of:

```
[1] "The total activity time for driver #264 is  705655.37272048"
```

My question is, how can I expand this code to find the activity for each other driver? (There are 374 unique drivers, each with thousands of points.) I have tried to replicate the above code using a loop that would calculate the time difference for each DriveNo, but I am new to R and I my understanding of loop syntax isn't great.

Can I filter into separate dataframes using a method like this? (This gives an error to do with unexpected bracketing).

```
for (i in seq_along(taxi_noOutlier$DriveNo))
{
taxi_[[i]] <- filter(taxi_noOutlier, DriveNo == [[i]])
}
```

and then use my original code on each one? Or is there a more efficient way? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your data with `dput()` function? It's not convient for us to reproduce your data only with your data content. We want a precise way something like `df <- data.frame(...)`.

Comment: Single `taxi_[[i]]` and `[[i]]` is  invalid. Usually, `[]` must follow a defined object, like `df[[i]]`.

Comment: structure(list(DriveNo = c(156, 187, 297, 89, 79, 191), Date.and.Time = structure(c(1391209200.73917, 
1391209201.14846, 1391209201.22007, 1391209201.47085, 1391209201.63114, 
1391209202.04855), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Latitude = c(41.883670807, 41.928543091, 41.891067505, 41.793178558, 
    41.900276184, 41.852306366), Longitude = c(12.48777771, 12.469037056, 
    12.492704391, 12.432122231, 12.46274662, 12.577406883)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Nice. It can be better if you provide it in the question `taxi_noOutlier <- structure(...)`.

Comment: So in the code, datelist = for(i in seq_along(taxi_noOutlier$DriveNo)) filter(taxi_noOutlier, DriveNo == i)$Date.and.Time
dlstandard = as.POSIXlt(datelist)
diffsum <- as.numeric(sum(Filter(function(x) x <= 60, difftime(tail(dlstandard, -1), head(dlstandard, -1), units = 'secs'))))
print(paste("The total activity time for driver #i is ", diffsum))                                 
what is the correct syntax for how to represent the replacing of 'i' with the iterating number each loop?

Comment: Sorry am new to this, will try to do that now.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, you had better to show what's your specific desired result  for your example data. So that we can check our answer.

Comment: `DriveNo = c(156, 187, 297, 89, 79, 191)`  doesn't include `264`, it should be consistent with your question.

Comment: Ok thanks I added that also. The crux of my question I guess is just the syntax of how to format loops in R to include the iterating value. In Python 'i' would just be a variable that you write in. My understanding was that in R you had to put [[i]] but that doesn't seem to work for me unless its directly referencing an dataframe index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group_by` each `DriveNo` get the difference between consecutive `Date.and.Time`, remove the values which are less than a minute and `sum` the differences.

```
library(dplyr)

taxi_noOutlier %>%
  group_by(DriveNo) %>%
  mutate(difftime =  difftime(Date.and.Time, lag(Date.and.Time), units = 'secs')) %>%
  filter(difftime <= 60) %>%
  summarise(diffsum = sum(as.numeric(difftime), na.rm = TRUE)) -> result

result
```

Comment: That was so easy and worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need.
The separate dataframes are stored in the list `taxi.list`.

```
taxi.list <- list()
for (i in taxi_noOutlier$DriveNo){ 
name <- paste0("taxi_",i)    
taxi.list[[name]] <-  filter(taxi_noOutlier, DriveNo == i)
#same as
#taxi.list[[name]] <- taxi_noOutlier %>% filter(DriveNo == i)
}
```

Comment: I'm trying that now, but there's 3 million data points so will take a while. I think maybe its not the most efficient approach just looping over the DriveNo column as each driver has thousands of data points so its probably doing redundant calculations for the same driver over and over. Thankyou

Comment: If there's 3 million data points, I think it's not necessary to store them in a list, because it can always easy to extract out with `filter(taxi_noOutlier, DriveNo == i)`. If you just want to calculate the time difference, then the other answer is satisfying.